# Help trimming extruded faces at intersection going through seperate object

Tags: mesh, modifiers, 3d-printing, knife-tool, makehuman

[image]

I'm new to blender. I'm having a problem removing a couple parts of a MakeHuman model. I am trying to remove the mouth cavity and eye sockets. Then I want to close up the holes. I'm starting with the mouth. I went into the head and deleted the mouth cavity leaving a little part to trim off.

I'm not even sure if Blender is able to do what I want. I then created a cylinder and placed it just on the inside of the mouth. I tried a boolean mod but it didn't work.

I want to cut off the part inside the cylinder. Then trim the edges of the cylinder to the mouth opening to "cap" off the mouth. Not necessarily in that order. Please forgive me if my terminology isn't correct.

The image is from the inside of the head. I hope I explained it clearly enough. I also removed the top face of the cylinder for clarity.

The purpose of this is to be able to 3D print these figures in resin for scale rc models.

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Thank you for the input. I didn't think it was descriptive enough either. But I don't know the technical terms to know what to ask. That is one of the problems with learning something new. I do appreciate the comments. It just further helps the learning process.

Comment: Hi! Is there a reason why you want to use a boolean operation? The Makehuman meshes have a clean topology. Just select an edge loop of the lips (Alt+click), delete the loop (key X), hover over the cavity, selected linked vertices (key L), and delete it (X). Then select the edge loop of the hole that you want to fill and grid fill it (Ctrl+F).